# How to handle cron execution time and user wait

Tags: linux, cron

I have scheduled a cron job that is executed every minute.

This cron job generates a pdf file using a distant web service. This operation alone takes a few seconds (something like 3 seconds), that means the cron job will be able to generate 20 pdf files per minute approximately.

If the visitor requests 60 documents, that means it will take 3 minutes for the server to generate all the pdf files.

Executing parallel cron jobs to do this task is not possible as all the files request must be handled individually for database relationships and integrity reasons. Basically, each file can only be handle one by one.

Therefore, is there any logic I could apply in order to :

1. execute multiple occurrences of the same cron job to speed up the process and decrease the user waiting time
2. and make the file creation process handled by one cron job only so that a specific creation process is not handled by another cron job doing the same task.

Thank you

Comment: Databases can handle multiple requests at the same time. Banks rely on this. So I do not understand that part

Comment: Each time the cron job will take care a file creation process, it will update the file status to 1 at the very end of the process (3 seconds). If parallel cron job is launched for the same entry before the status is set to 1, it will be a mess up.

Comment: Take a look at "queuing systems".

Comment: I'm a little confused about why you are using a cronjob to handle a user request.

Comment: Why cannot your database handle relationships and integrity with multiple requests going on at the same time? I also think Cron is the wrong technology you are using

Comment: @dan08 because the webservice generating the file can time out and it does respond with the proper error message. Therefore I am using a cron job because the download must be rescheduled if the webservice times out. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: It does not. I think you need to go back to the drawing board

Comment: is you cron job a script? why don't you perform several webservice requests in parallel?